# How to remove duplicates in mongoDB with mongoose(NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in MongoDB where there are around (~200k records). My sample record would look like,

```
{
    name:String,
    slug:String,
    metaDes:String,
    content:String,
    parentID:String,
    thumbnail:String,
    display:Boolean,
}
```

I am having a lot of duplicate records in the collection having same `slug`

I want to remove duplicate records based on `slug`
Is there any fast way to remove all duplicates with mongoose(Nodejs)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove  duplicate records in the collection having the same `slug`

```js
db.table.aggregate([
 {
     "$group": {
         _id: {slug: "$slug"},
         slugs: { $addToSet: "$_id" } ,
         count: { $sum : 1 }
     }
 },
 {
     "$match": {
         count: { "$gt": 1 }
     }
 }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
   doc.slugs.shift();
   db.table.remove({
       _id: {$in: doc.slugs}
   });
})
```

Refarnce [link](https://weknowinc.com/blog/how-remove-duplicates-mongodb)